# Video watch time with Timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to get videos from the YouTube and trying to add a timer to get watch time of a video by the user. I have a `watchTime` variable that I want to increase each second to the latest value while the `_controller.value.isPlaying` is true. However, the output is not as expected and value is increased very quickly and not by the one second.

Here is my code:

```
class _WatchVideoState extends State<WatchVideo> {

  final _pageController = PageController();
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int watchTime = 0 ;
  late Timer _timer;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: widget.videoID,
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: false,
    )
    )..addListener(() {
      if (mounted && _controller.value.isPlaying){
          _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
            watchTime++;
            print('The Watch time is:  ${watchTime++}');
          });

      }
      else {
        _timer.cancel();
        print('Video is Stopped${watchTime}');
      }
    });
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.courseLessons.week.toString()),
        backgroundColor: pallet_orange,
      ),
      body:
          Column(
            children:[
              Expanded(
                child: PageView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _pageController,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: pallet_orange),
                                  onPressed: () {

                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,)),
                              SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              Flexible(child: Text(widget.courseLessons
                                  .lessonTitle.toString(), overflow: TextOverflow
                                  .ellipsis,)),
                              SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              ElevatedButton(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: pallet_orange),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,)),
                            ],

                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                          YoutubePlayer(
                                progressColors: const ProgressBarColors(
                                    playedColor: pallet_orange,
                                    handleColor: pallet_orange),
                                controller: _controller,
                                showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                                onReady: () => print('Ready'),
                          ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),

            ]
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a Stopwatch().

```
final stopwatch = Stopwatch();
bool completionStatus = false;
  double stopWatchTime = 0;
  var roundedWatchedTime = 0;
```

and here is the init method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: widget.videoID,
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: false,
    )
    )..addListener(() {
      var totalDuration = 0;
      if (mounted && _controller.value.isPlaying){
        roundedWatchedTime = 0;
        stopwatch.start();
        stopWatchTime = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
        roundedWatchedTime = stopWatchTime.round();
        if (roundedWatchedTime >= 30) {
          stopWatchCompletionStatus();
        }
      }
      else if (mounted && !_controller.value.isPlaying){
        stopwatch.stop();
      }
      else if (!mounted){
        stopwatch.stop();
        stopwatch.reset();
        roundedWatchedTime = 0;
        stopWatchTime = 0;
      }

      else {
        print('Nothing');
      }

    });
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use videos current duration to get watch time

```
Duration? currentDuration = _controller?.value.position;
```